# Why can't I connect to my create-react-app local development server from my other computer?

Tags: reactjs, networking, create-react-app

I have a react client running locally on my machine using react-scripts. I can work with it normally on that machine. I also have a nodeJS server running on a different port. I figured I should be able to connect to these from my other computer or cellphone and I can connect to the server using my local IPv4 address + server port, but when I try to connect to the client using the same address + client port I get a loading spinner in the browser tab and the connection times out after some time.

I figured it might be a firewall issue so I added an inbound rule (and an outbound one though I don't think that should do anything) on the machine running the client+server letting all traffic through the relevant port but this changed nothing. When I do a network diagnostic using chrome from the tab where I can't open the client it tells me the webpage is online but isn't responding. I get the same behavior when connection from my cellphone.

One thing that might be of note is that when I serve the build folder of my app through my NodeJS server, the app opens just fine on the other computer using the server port but I don't want to have to build my app after every change manually.

What could this be down to?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, all devices are on the same router. The laptop running the servers and the cellphone are connected via wireless and the PC is connected via ethernet.

Comment: I think you will need to set up NAT on your router for it to know where to redirect your requests

Comment: I'm not very good with networking but from what I do know, NAT configuration shouldn't be needed. I forgot to mention all the devices in question are connected to the same router (though the laptop running the servers and the phone are on wireless and the PC is on ethernet).